# budling and download json files for highcharts

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts, blob

I am working on highcharts, where graph is plot from multiple json files from same location (same azure blob storage). Is it possible to bundle it and download as a whole (from a single request)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are requesting through ajax. getting multiple response for single request is not possible.
For the same scenario what i had done is I had used nested ajax call and plotted the graph. 
Let me know if  you have different solution.